# div does not do what it is supposed to do

Tags: php, html, css

[image: the blue is me, the other color is my chat mate]

it is supposed to be line broken

but the divs sit aside each other it is supposed that they dont do that. I the blue messages should be floated to the right, while the other to the left but they stack up at the side. pls help me out. If you cant view the picthen visit this link https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJcPi.jpg.

heres my css:

```
.convo_mes_me{
background:blue;
padding:3px;
margin:8px 3px;
height:auto;
color:#fff;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
float:right;
max-width:45%;
border-radius:5px;
}

.convo_mes_him{
border-radius:5px;
max-width:45%;
background:#f2f2f2;
padding:3px;
margin:8px 3px;
height:auto;
width:auto;
float:left;
text-overflow:ellipsis;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}

heres my HTML in php:

```
if($sender == $user){
        echo "
        <br />
        <div class='convo_mes_me'>
        $sender: $message
        </div><br />
        ";
    }else{
        echo "
        <br />
        <div class='convo_mes_him'>
        $sender: $message
        </div><br />
        ";
    }
```

Comment: add a <p style="clear:both;"></p>after every message

Answer (score 1):

That's just how floating divs work. You should have some kind of clearfix between the messages to separate them. I would suggest you to either add a `<div>` between them or wrap each message in another `<div>`. In both cases, this new div should be `float: left` and `width: 100%`.

Also, get rid of the `<br>`s.

Comment: I want messages to have auto width which depends on how long the text is. Let me try the <div></div> in between trick.

Comment: I too suggest the same, you should go with clearfix for after each and remove <br>'s

Comment: i removed the <br />. What is clearfix.

Comment: worked bro, thanks so much. I added clear:both; then it worked. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are just floating your divs. And since the divs can fit beside each other they will.

You could probably insert an empty 100% div styled with clear:both between each message...

Check out this page for crazy float goodness https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

Comment: yea, that was great idea.